# Warning for new tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging, warnings

I have a reasonable idea for a feature request.

When a user is creating a tag the system will recognize that and point out that the following tag is new, requiring the user to acknowledge the creation of the tag.

Possibly the message can show the names of similar tags (e.g. creating the tag [complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex) will show the name [complex-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-numbers) and [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis) and so on), and point out that it might fit under these tags instead of creating a new tag. The shown tags can be selected based on the tag name alone, or by searching the tag wiki excerpt for words appearing in the new tag (e.g. if I were to create a tag [cardinal-arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardinal-arithmetic) then a suggestion to use [cardinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardinals) instead should show up, as the tag excerpt contains such term).

My view is that such message should show for each and every new tag created by the question, so if someone decides to create five new tags, they should authorize five different tags.

This may help decrease the creation of essentially-duplicate tags, or new and essentially-over specific tags.

Comment: Something like that could also help (at least to some extent) with the problem mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11127/mistagged-algebraic-geometry-questions), i.e. tagging a question by (algebraic) and (geometry) instead (algebraic-geometry) and similar mistakes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure something like this already exists, but it is limited in scope (an algorithm determines if a to-be-created tag is close enough to another tag, e.g. catching singular/plural). I'm in favour of widening the scope.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Nothing like that exists. (Proof of concept in this very thread.)

Comment: @Martin: Yes, that was one of the triggers for the idea.

Comment: For example if you try to create (cardinal) on the main you get: *You are attempting to create the tag [cardinal]; however the tag [cardinals] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.* I guess this is what @Lord_Farin had in mind.

Comment: I found this on meta.SO: [Warning or confirmation on new tag creation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation). It is tagged ([meta-tag:status-planned]). Although the question is from 2011 and the last activity was 7 months ago.

Comment: @Martin: Hm. Well, I'm asking for a slightly better solution than just matching something by name, instead I suggest searching for keywords in the excerpt (or in fact, we can add "keywords" to tags!) as well.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, Martin: I didn't get such notice when I just created [taggin]...

Comment: What about some kind of review mechanism for new tags?

Comment: @Asaf That's just... disappointing. More power to this request!

Comment: @azimut: There is one, essentially, the list of newly created tags appear in one of the pages of the moderation tool available to the 10k users. But the system should make it "less easy" to create tags to begin with, not cause a lot of work for those which are already burdened with reviewing a lot of things on the site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks. I'm really looking forward to 10K to get the full picture...

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184851/you-are-attempting-to-create-a-tag-however-the-tag-already-exists) claims: *you cannot create a tag which differs from an existing tag only by the addition or removal of hyphens or a final S.* This should explain (taggin) vs (tagging).

Comment: @Martin: Ah, yes. That one is true. While it will hold if someone would try to create [cardinal] on main, it will fail to do so if someone would try to create [cardinal-arithmetics] tag. Moreover, I'm not trying to prevent the creation of new tags. Just to make sure that the user knows that there are other relevant options, and that they are well aware that they are creating a new tag.

Comment: @azimut: I might be mistaken, but I think that the [list of newly created tags](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) is available to all users, not only 10k+. (If you go to tags tab, you can choose 3 "orderings": popular, name, new.)

Comment: @Martin: I didn't know about that. I think that this feature would have been very good to perhaps avoid having some of these new tags.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Yeah, it's available for me. But it's like the list of tag synonym proposals: Only because it's available, you rarely have a look. So some kind of reviewing process would be great, where the new tags (or new tag synonym proposals) automatically appear in a review cue for high rep users. If I got Asaf Karagila right, something like this already exists for newly created tags to > 10k users.

Comment: @azimut: Not exactly, but it gives you a list of tags created recently, it's not a queue sort of thing.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry about the insane delay here. I wasn't aware of this post when [the new tag creation warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233897/155160) was implemented.

It is on for Math.SE now. Let me know if you see any weird behaviour.

Comment: Do all users get the warning or is it only for users below some reputation? (If the linked post contains information about this, then I did not notice it.) I'd prefer if the warning is given for all users.

Comment: @MartinSleziak The answer Adam links seems to say that the warning, when enabled on a site, is shown to »moderators and users with the "create new tags" privilege«. Indeed, I just tested it, and it was shown to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Arthur. It seems that I should have read the post a bit more carefully.

Comment: I have noticed that the warning only appears on the main site. Perhaps it could be reasonable to extend this on the main site? (I found out this by mistake - I wanted to check the exact text shown in the warning. So I tried to create a new tag in this question - and I found out that I was shown nothing.)

Comment: I meant to say that it would be good to extend this *to meta*. Sorry for the mistake in the previous comment.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Easy enough to enable it, but best to start by opening a new discussion here on meta to see if folks generally feel the warning would help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have created a separate question about that: [Warning when creating a new tag on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30068).