# Warning when creating a new tag on meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging, meta, warnings

When a new tag is created on the main site, you get a warning before you can continue - this prevents creation of a tag by mistake. This was implemented as a result of this feature request: [Warning for new tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11140).<sup>1</sup>

[image: Screenshot]

Only today I realized that this warning is only enabled on main site and not on meta.<sup>2</sup> I think that it make sense to display the same warning on meta - for the same reasons, mainly to prevent creating a new tag when somebody makes a typo.

Originally I suggested this just as a comment on the older thread, but based on recommendation which [I was given there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11140/warning-for-new-tags/21749?noredirect=1#comment128525_21749), I am opening a separate feature request for this.

<sup>1</sup>Thanks to Andrews [for the screenshot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49885686#49885686).

<sup>2</sup>In fact, I was quite confident that this actually works on both sites - which is why I created a new tag on meta by mistake. My intention was simply to see what exactly the warning says - and, to my surprise, I was allowed to save the edit without being shown any warning at all. (To this I should add that I apologize for bumping an old thread - that wasn't my intention.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not seeing any objections, so I enabled the new tag creation warning here on meta as well.